# Validating uniqueness of one attribute across two separate columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I need to validate the uniqueness two fields.

Model

```
:name
:original_url #(this cannot match any url or original_url)
:url #(this cannot match any url or original_url)
```

I can validate each one individually

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: {:url, :original_url}
```

But I can't work out how I can secure against both fields. I'm also a touch concerned about performance (the table has 2m records). The fields are indexed so I'm hoping that will be enough.

Any idea what the best way to do this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to bkunzi above for pointing me on the right track.

validate :ensure_urls_unique

```
def ensure_urls_unique
  urls = [self.url, self.original_url].compact # To allow 'nil' to match
  if Job.where("original_url IN (?) OR ad_url IN (?)",urls, urls).where(name:self.name).where.not(id:self.id).exists?
    self.errors.add(:base, "The urls must be unique!")
  else
    return true
  end
end
```

It's worth noting that .exists? performs a fair bit better than .empty? on large sample sets or where you're likely to get matches.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be at both the database level and in the Rails Model.  I can help you with the latter and hopefully someone can chime in about how to add this via SQL as well.  I'll keep this in "Model" context since you didnt specify the name:

In your model.rb file:

```
validate :ensure_unique_for_both_cols

def ensure_unique_for_both_cols
  if self.original_url || self.url
    #Ensure no record matching this exists in either field
    unless Model.where("original_url = ? OR url = ?",self.original_url, self.url).empty?
       self.errors.add(:base, "The url must be unique!")
    end
  end     
end
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. 
This tests if the original_url matches any original_urls, or if url matches any urls. 
I need the test to check whether original_url matches any original_url or ad_url and likewise for url.